# how to get Row number partition with id and date of next day from below query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After group by I get result like this:

```
emp_Reader_id    DT              eventid
----------------------------------------
    9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000 0
    9999    2018-10-22 06:00:00.000 1
```

After insert into temp table to get row number

```
declare @tempProcesstable as table(
    [id] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [time_stamp] datetime NULL,
    [AccessType] varchar(3)  NULL) 

insert into @tempProcesstable 
    select distinct 
        t1.emp_Reader_id, t1.DT,t1.eventid 
    from   
        daily_attendance_data t2 
    join 
        trnevents t1 on t1.emp_reader_id = t2.emp_reader_id 
    where   
        (CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_Date, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-20', 23) 
        and CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_date, 23) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-21', 23))
        and (t1.DT >= t2.in_time and t1.DT <= t2.out_time)
        and t1.emp_reader_id = 9999
    group by 
        t1.emp_Reader_id, t1.dt, t1.eventid 
    order by 
        t1.emp_reader_id, DT asc

; With CheckIns As 
(
     Select 
         Rowemp_reader_id = Row_Number() Over (Partition by id, Cast(time_stamp As Date) Order By time_stamp),
         id, time_stamp,
         [Date] = Cast(time_stamp As Date),
         [Time] = Cast(time_stamp As Time(0))
     From  
         @tempProcesstable
)
select * from checkins
```

My current output:

```
Rowemp_reader_id    id  time_stamp  Date    Time
---------------------------------------------------
1   9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000 2018-10-21  08:00:00
1   9999    2018-10-22 06:00:00.000 2018-10-22  06:00:00
```

My expected output:

```
Rowemp_reader_id    id  time_stamp  Date    Time
---------------------------------------------------------
1   9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000 2018-10-21  08:00:00
2   9999    2018-10-22 06:00:00.000 2018-10-22  06:00:00
```

Comment: What's the difference between *output* and *expected output*

Comment: Might be diff is the first col

Comment: row number is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using `Row_Number() Over (Partition by id Order By time_stamp)`

```
declare @tempProcesstable as table(
    [id] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [time_stamp] datetime NULL,
    [AccessType] varchar(3)  NULL) 
insert into @tempProcesstable 

        select distinct t1.emp_Reader_id, t1.DT,t1.eventid from   daily_attendance_data t2 join trnevents t1
on t1.emp_reader_id=t2.emp_reader_id where   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_Date, 23) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-20', 23) 
                       and CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_date, 23) <=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-21', 23))
                   and
                   (t1.DT >=t2.in_time 
                       and  t1.DT <=t2.out_time)
                           and t1.emp_reader_id=9999
                               group by t1.emp_Reader_id,t1.dt,t1.eventid order by t1.emp_reader_id,DT asc
                  ; With CheckIns
As (Select Rowemp_reader_id = Row_Number() Over (Partition by id Order By time_stamp),
        id, time_stamp,
        [Date] = Cast(time_stamp As Date),

        [Time] = Cast(time_stamp As Time(0))
    From @tempProcesstable)
    select * from checkins
```

Comment: thank you . i used this in my pivot table but output changed

Comment: i need it in single row id emp_name Date CHECK1 CHECK2 Total1 CHECK3 CHECK4
1000 Johir Uddin Late Siraj 2018-10-20 06:57:42 17:36:20 10:38:38 NULL NULL
1000 Johir Uddin Late Siraj 2018-10-21 NULL NULL NULL 07:08:16 17:38:24